# D3 Tree - How to expand tree to show and highlight all nodes of same name?

Tags: d3.js

I am using [Patrick Brockmann's CollapsibleTree Search](http://bl.ocks.org/PBrockmann/0f22818096428b12ea23) for my D3 Tree, where the tree is expanded to show and highlight links and nodes based on the term selected in the `Select2`, `#search`.  This works fine.

I now have a scenario where I need to automatically expand a tree by clicking a button to show and highlight (as per Patrick Brockmann's example) ALL nodes matching with the same name, i.e. `d.name` =  'Bill'.

Nodes that do not have that name can be shown, but I only want nodes of that name shown in red and with red connector as per Patrick’s example.

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfyge2rp/2/)

Comment: Question in unclear. Please explain in detail with some more code. In fiddle I am not able to see `select`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ramachandran_123456/gp3hejtc/1/  , can you check if this is what is required?

Comment: Ram, not really, I need to have all nodes with the same name, e.g. 'Bill'  shown and highlighted as per OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question well, it already works like this, you just need to take the input elsewhere and call up the search.

For example, I added an input text in the html and recall the search every time the value changes.

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" value="test">

$("#searchText").on("input", function(e) {
    clearAll(root);
    expandAll(root);
    update(root);

    searchField = "d.name";
    searchText = e.target.value;
    //console.log(searchText);
    searchTree(root);
    root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
    update(root);
})
```

this is the patch to get "Patrick Brockmann's CollapsibleTree Search" example working with an input text

```
--- index.html.orig     2019-09-04 01:06:06.545853315 +0200
+++ index.html  2019-09-04 01:13:30.291689888 +0200
@@ -55,6 +55,7 @@
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css"></link>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

+<input type="text" id="searchText" value="test">
 <div id="block_container">
    <div id="searchName"></div>
 </div>
@@ -157,6 +158,19 @@     searchTree(root);
     root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
     update(root);
+})
+
+$("#searchText").on("input", function(e) {
+    clearAll(root);
+    expandAll(root);
+    update(root);
+
+    searchField = "d.name";
+    searchText = e.target.value;
+    console.log(searchText);
+    searchTree(root);
+    root.children.forEach(collapseAllNotFound);
+    update(root);
 })
```

Comment: Could you show this in an updated fiddle?  I do also need the highlighting of nodes and links for the searched node...

Comment: there https://jsfiddle.net/5jdcfLn4/ I've forked your fiddle, the highlighting isn't working with your fiddle (maybe some css?) but is working with "Patrick Brockmann's CollapsibleTree Search" example, I've it working locally

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 there https://jsfiddle.net/5jdcfLn4/1/ , the highlighting wasn't working because you removed some "found" condition (and it was missing in the css too)